# How to fix Error parsing file template: Encountered

Tags: android

Unable to parse template "ASClass"
Error message:

> This template did not produce a Java class or an interface
>   package com.example.smarther1.sqlitetest.SquliteDatas;
>
> Error parsing file template: Encountered "DATE" at File Header.java[line 2,  column 7]
>   Was expecting one of:
>        ...
>       "{" ...

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to parse template "Class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497266/unable-to-parse-template-class)

Answer (score 2):

Go to `File->setting->editor->file` and code templates, select Class in the files tab and write this:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "" && ${Is_your_class_abstract_Reply_yes_no} == "no")
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};
#parse("File Header.java") public class ${NAME} {

}
#elseif (${Is_your_class_abstract_Reply_yes_no} == "yes")
#parse("File Header.java") public abstract class ${NAME} {

}
#end
```