# Unable to parse template "Class"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create class in android but i got this error

> Unable to parse template "Class"
>   Error message: This template did not produce a Java class or an interface

and in Event log I got this error

> FileNotFoundException: Entry fileTemplates//code/Google Test Fixture SetUp Method.cc.ft not found in /D:/Android%20Studio/lib/idea.jar

this my app bulid gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
  {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hh.ss.msed"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.2'


    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'


}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
   }
  }
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this bulid gradle project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }

 allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

what the wrong?

Comment: Come on. Are we supposed to guess what the code looks like?

Comment: this main activity i don't have any code 
when I create new project I can't create new class

Comment: @John3136 this happend when you click File > New > Java class

Comment: I've had this same issue with IntelliJ Idea (Android Studio is based on IntelliJ), and the fix was exactly the same as proposed here.

Answer (score 59):

Go to File->setting->editor->file and code templates, select Class in the files tab and paste this:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end #parse("File Header.java") public class ${NAME} { }
```

[image: Screenshot of editor]

Comment: There should be a way to get Google or IntelliJ (or whoever maintains Android Studio) to fix this error. I really doubt that it's because anything the OP or I did.

Comment: Great.. Thanks a lot.. It helped me.. But I'd like to know about that, that why was that happening and how you solved it.

Answer (score 47):

I have the same problem, and got it solved by adding in the `idea.vmoptions` or `idea64.vmoptions` the following line:

```
-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false
```

as showed in [JetBrains Support by user Wojciech Fred](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206922365-Unable-to-parse-template-Class-Error-message-This-template-did-not-produce-a-Java-class-or-an-interface-during-New-Java-Class)

Seems to be a fix applied by oracle to the Java 8 Update 144

I hope it helps :D

Edit:
In Android Studio, the file is called studio.vmoptions, and can be found inside the configuration directory, but it is more easy if you go to the "help>Edit custom VM options" menu:
[Android Studio Configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html)

Comment: where can we find the idea.vmoptions file in a Linux Machine ?

Comment: In Android Studio, the easiest way is by the menus. In "Help >  Edit custom VM options", the editor opens the file, and you could add the line there.

Comment: Yeah found it , Android Studio -> Help -> Edit Custom VM options

Comment: This fixed it for me on the latest Studio (2.3.3) on Ubuntu 64 bit. Thankyou so much!

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 2.3, and I can't find any files called studio.vmoptions, by any means. I tried help>edit custom VM options, as you suggested, but that said studio.exe.vmoptions didn't exist, and asked if I wanted to create it. Is this likely to be the file you're talking about? It put it in Android Studio\bin

Comment: I think this is the file we are talking about, but maybe this link could help you a little more: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

Answer (score 32):

I encountered something like this in android studio. What i did was I opened IntelliJ Idea (Since Android studio is based on it), and copied the default text of respective template and pasted in android studio respective file.

Go to File->setting->editor->file and code templates, select Class in the files tab and write this

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end #parse("File Header.java") public class ${NAME} { }
```

Comment: I think this should be the answer!

Comment: So is this an Android Studio installation problem?

Comment: This is not adding the Superclass for me (for example, ... extends View). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 11):

I didn't encounter this error before. I faced this issue only after I reinstall my android studio(version 3.0). Creating new Class give the following error as mentioned in the question.

> Unable to parse template "Class" Error message: This template did not
>   produce a Java class or an interface

So there are two ways to get rid of this error

### **Option 1 is @Semicolon answer**

Go to **File->Setting->Editor->File and Code Templates**, select Class in the files tab and write this

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end #parse("File Header.java") public class ${NAME} { }
```

### **Option 2 is @Angel Castelo answer**

Add the following line to your VM custom option(studio.vmoptions).

```
-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false
```

My suggestion is to add it using android studio(**Select Help->Edit Custom VM Options->then add the code**). If you didn't create Custom VM Option File before then it will prompt a dialogue mentioning "Custom VM Option file not exist. do you want to create it" Select yes and the studio will create a Custom VM option file. Then follow the steps(above mentioned).

### **Conclusion**

Which one is better?

When I first encounter this issue I choose option one and its worked well until I started my next project. When I started a new project the issue appear again so I visit this page and found **option 2** and it worked perfectly for me.

When we follow **option 2** creating new project doesn't trigger this issue again unlike **option 1**.

### **Further Reading**

[Intellij Support Page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206922365-Unable-to-parse-template-Class-Error-message-This-template-did-not-produce-a-Java-class-or-an-interface-during-New-Java-Class)

[Android Developer Page](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html)

[Read more about Android Studio file templates](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-java-class.html)

Answer (score 8):

In your, IntelliJ IDE go to Help => Edit Custom VM Options and Add to your idea.vmoptions or idea64.vmoptions the following line:

`-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false`

You can read more about it [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties) and [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206922365-Unable-to-parse-template-Class-Error-message-This-template-did-not-produce-a-Java-class-or-an-interface-during-New-Java-Class).

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was working before but suddenly started to show this error message.
I tried some of above answers but didn't help so clearing caches fixed my problem.

On **Intellij** Go to **File > Invalidate caches/Restart** and select **Invalidate and Restart** option.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Yes simply,this is in the best case  try to do it before any other answers

Comment: Encounter similar problem "unable to parse template class error there should only be 1 yaml document per file", solved by Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 4):

the trick by Semicolon works
Similarly for adding interfaces go to

```
Android Studio -> Preferences -> File and Code Templates -> Files -> Interface
```

and add the following code

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end #parse("File Header.java") public interface ${NAME} { }
```

Answer (score 4):

This all answer may be right, and work very fine, I use this options for few days and it's work for me too, but there are one other option and i think which is much better because, this option is given by **[android developer](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-java-class.html)** which is as give as below:

**For Class file template:**

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end

    #if (${IMPORT_BLOCK} != "")${IMPORT_BLOCK}
    #end
    #parse("File Header.java")

    #if (${VISIBILITY} == "PUBLIC")public #end #if (${ABSTRACT} == "TRUE")abstract #end #if (${FINAL} == "TRUE")final #end class ${NAME} #if (${SUPERCLASS} != "")extends ${SUPERCLASS} #end #if (${INTERFACES} != "")implements ${INTERFACES} #end {
    }
```

**Interface file template**

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end

#if (${IMPORT_BLOCK} != "")${IMPORT_BLOCK}
#end
#parse("File Header.java")

#if (${VISIBILITY} == "PUBLIC")public #end enum ${NAME} #if (${INTERFACES} != "")implements ${INTERFACES} #end {
#end {
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The reason is you maybe installed the 64 bit version on a 32 bit machine. I had the same problem. If you have 32-bit OS, try to uninstall 64-bit version of Android Studio and install 32-bit version from this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a Mac using IntelliJ IDEA 14 and I found the file idea.vmoptions here:

```
~/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 (Right click Show Package Contents) /Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
```

I then added the same line that the top answerer suggested:

```
-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false
```

Answer (score 2):

I had occur same problem but I have fixed this problem by following steps:

Step 1: Go to File menu >> Setting

Step 2: then click on Editor and then File and code templates

Step 3: Now select Class

Step4 : After that paste this code in editor. For more details see the image.

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end #parse("File Header.java") public class ${NAME} { }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you, like me, tried everything to no avail, check if there's anything under `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `File Types` -> `File type auto-detected by file content` and remove from there if it's the file name that is producing this error.

I have no idea how I managed to add the file name there, but it was there and was causing this error for me (it was working with other file names and only the one listed that got me that error).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same error and the error was due to a bad syntax in the Java File header template. I solved it in the following way:

Go to:

```
Android Studio -> Preferences -> File and Code Templates -> Includes -> File Header
```

If you have defined some variables in the template, check how the variables are defined, should be (for instance):

```
#set( $USER = "Your Name")
```

instead of

```
#set( USER  "Your Name")
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it just appeared I didn't change any settings or update Android studio what so ever. I solved it by selecting

```
File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to File
then setting -> editor -> file and code templates, select Class in the files tab and paste this
" #if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end #parse("File Header.java") public class ${NAME} { }"
then click on Apply.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue with my Idea 14. But when it was just installed it was not the case, later I found it appeared after protobuf plugin was installed. If you uninstall protobuf plugin it works again.

Maybe will help somebody...