# Android Studio - Entry fileTemplates//Singleton.java.ft not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm always getting this error after using Android Studio 3.0.1:

> Entry fileTemplates//Singleton.java.ft not found in C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/resources_en.jar

Also the following error pops up every time I try to create a new class:

> Unable to parse template "Class"
>   Error message: This template did not produce a Java class or an interface

I'm able to solve this second problem by following this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656033/7746134

But I have to do this each time I restart Android Studio. I'm not sure whether these two errors are related or not.